# Move the mouse in wpf

Tags: wpf

I'm currently looking for a way to move the mouse in wpf. All I found was unmanaged method calls which I couldn't implement reliably. Is there an easy way to move the mouse cursor to some place, ie. after a doubleclick? I'm surely missing something here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll, then set [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx).

Comment: While this might be a way, I'm quite reluctant to reference System.Windows.Forms in a WPF application.

Comment: I know this is an old question and all but, I'm actually curious if you happened to find a way to do this without adding the System.Windows.Forms reference?